# How to run linux command from JAVA?

Tags: java, linux, bash, plugins, runcommand

I want to make a java web interface that run bash process in the background. So, in java how can I run linux command like "ls -al" or run bash script. Is there any package or java plugin that able to invoke OS command in JAVA?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

As I showed here: [Compiling a C Source through javacode using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900749/compiling-a-c-source-through-javacode-using-gcc/35901407#35901407)

You could use `ProcessBuilder` to do that:

```
String directory = "/home/user";
String[] commands = {"ls", "-al"};

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(new File(directory));
pb.command(commands);

Process p = pb.start();

OuputStream out = p.getOutputStream(); // to send other commands/data
InputStream in = p.getInputStream(); // to read console response
// process the streams
```

Answer (score 0):

As already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403259/3501205)

You can use the `Runtime.exec()` method.